# Wrong instructions when posting an answer on mobile site

Tags: bug, status-completed, mobile-web

If you are an unregistered user or you are not logged in, here's what it says when you try to post an answer on the mobile site:

[image: It is an answer, not a question.]

Comment: And if you browse the full site (from mobile) does it appear correctly as "answer" in there?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Yes. The problem is on mobile site only.

Comment: @Yep saw it. Mobile theme by the way, anyone can browse it from a desktop computer as well by clicking the "mobile" link in the footer of any page. :)

Comment: Most of website that hold open by mobile will have some issue. We can't blame it. Why? Cause it just like asking to control 2sites at a time. Of course a project must have be testing too. So, problem like this will be fix after been report.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Good eyes there.

The mobile template for the page was incorrect. It is no longer incorrect.

The fix will be out in the next build.